# Did Themis preside over "the proper relation between man and woman" and the concept of the family?

Tags: greek, titans

I recently saw the following quote in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Themis) on Themis:

> Themis presided over the proper relation between man and woman[citation needed], the basis of the rightly ordered family (the family was seen as the pillar of the deme.)

The "citation needed" was added by me. I've looked through the translated sources at [theoi.com](https://www.theoi.com/Titan/TitanisThemis.html), and I cannot see anything that backs this up. I can't see anything that suggests Themis had strong opinions on gender roles or on what a family should look like, or that she enforced any sort of law on people regarding those things.

Is there an untranslated source which backs up this claim? Perhaps something I've missed?

Comment: You did well by adding "citation needed". The lack of sources and the poor formatting of that specific paragraph of the Themis page makes me suspect that whoever wrote it does not have a solid academic background and was trying to push a personal (possibly ideological) interpretation.

Comment: Based on the uncited source, because the theory behind the assertion is strongly supportable, my guess is that it comes from later philosophical treatment of the mythological texts specifically.  (Sound like something out of Plato, but I can't offhand think of a reference.)